# How to Truncate Mysql Table in Hadoop(Map-Reduce)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, truncate

We are using Mysql Database for storing output in map-Reduce(hadoop). We need to Truncate the table before inserting data into it.

Is there a way to do it using Map-Reduce Program.

Comment: Are you going to put this data in mappers or reducers. If in reducers, how many reducers have you set for your job?

Comment: i am using only one reducer & mapper.